# What is this "for system_time between" in my SQL Server select query?

Tags: sql-server

I found a query in some code that looks like this:

```
select * 
from myview 
for system_time between @fromDt and @toDt --what is this?
where countryId = @Id
```

I've never seen a `for system_time between X and Y` in a query.  What does it mean?  Where can I find documentation about this or examples using it?

[Here is the syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) for a `select` and it mentions a `for` clause, but that only mentions XML, JSON, and BROWSE options ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173812.aspx)).

Comment: Does the query work?   Is there a column named system_time in your view?

Comment: It's a feature new to 2016: [Temporal Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in [Temporal Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx), which is a new feature to 2016 as explained in comments:

> [**How do I query temporal data?**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx#Anchor_3)
>
> The `SELECT statement FROM<table>` clause has a new clause `FOR
>   SYSTEM_TIME` with five temporal-specific sub-clauses to query data
>   across the current and history tables. This new SELECT statement
>   syntax is supported directly on a single table, propagated through
>   multiple joins, and through views on top of multiple temporal tables.

It then also says:

> FOR SYSTEM_TIME filters out rows that have period of validity with
>   zero duration (SysStartTime = SysEndTime). Those rows will be
>   generated if you perform multiple updates on the same primary key
>   within the same transaction. In that case, temporal querying surfaces
>   only row versions before the transactions and ones that became actual
>   after the transactions. If you need to include those rows in the
>   analysis, query the history table directly.